# Tell browser not to do spellcheck for a given textarea

Tags: html, xhtml

I have a text area that is not meant for spell checking. It is making my app look ugly.

How do I tell the browser to skip spell checking for this text area?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding this parameter to the html tag.

```
spellcheck='false'
```

Comment: Do you have a reference for that?